# Copy a struct content into uint64 in Go

Tags: go

I want to copy a strcuture's values into uint64, what's the proper method without unsafe?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type T struct {
    id [7]byte
    no uint8
}

func main() {
    t1 := T{[7]byte{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'}, 7}
    var u uint64

    //TODO: copy t1's content into u (both id and no)
    //u = *((*uint64)(unsafe.Pointer(&t1)))

    fmt.Println(t1, u)
}
```

Comment: Did you try type assertion `u = t1.(T)`? I don't actually think it would work but still worth a try. Another way would be to parse the content of t1 yourself and fill the fields in T.

Comment: It's not clear to me what this would even mean, since I don't believe Go makes any requirements on system word size and endianness; you could find that your most significant byte is `'A'`, `'D'`, `'E'`, or `7`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, on little-endian architectures, without using package `unsafe`,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

type T struct {
    id [7]byte
    no uint8
}

func Uint64LEFromT(t T) uint64 {
    return uint64(t.id[0]) | uint64(t.id[1])<<8 | uint64(t.id[2])<<16 | uint64(t.id[3])<<24 |
        uint64(t.id[4])<<32 | uint64(t.id[5])<<40 | uint64(t.id[6])<<48 | uint64(t.no)<<56
}

func Uint64LEToT(t *T, v uint64) {
    t.id[0] = byte(v)
    t.id[1] = byte(v >> 8)
    t.id[2] = byte(v >> 16)
    t.id[3] = byte(v >> 24)
    t.id[4] = byte(v >> 32)
    t.id[5] = byte(v >> 40)
    t.id[6] = byte(v >> 48)
    t.no = byte(v >> 56)
}

func main() {
    t1, t2 := T{[7]byte{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'}, 7}, T{}
    var u1, u2 uint64

    //TODO: copy t1's content into u1 (both id and no)
    u1 = *((*uint64)(unsafe.Pointer(&t1)))
    fmt.Printf("t1 to u1 (unsafe): t1 %X u1 %X\n", t1, u1)

    //DONE:
    u2 = Uint64LEFromT(t1)
    fmt.Printf("t1 to u2 (safe):   t1 %X u2 %X\n", t1, u2)
    Uint64LEToT(&t2, u2)
    fmt.Printf("u2 to t2 (safe):   t2 %X u2 %X\n", t2, u2)
}
```

Output:

```
t1 to u1 (unsafe): t1 {41424344454647 7} u1 747464544434241
t1 to u2 (safe):   t1 {41424344454647 7} u2 747464544434241
u2 to t2 (safe):   t2 {41424344454647 7} u2 747464544434241
```

Comment: I like this method, but it seems only suitable for byte and uint8 structure.(I mean this case only). Am I right?  Is this method have other limitation?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try type cast?

```
u = uint64(t1.no)
```

Ah, ok. Did you try binary.Write / binary.Read ?

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
)

type T struct {
    id [7]byte
    no uint8
}

func main() {
    t1 := T{[7]byte{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'}, 7}
    var u uint64

    var b bytes.Buffer
    binary.Write(&b, binary.LittleEndian, &t1)
    binary.Read(&b, binary.LittleEndian, &u)

    fmt.Println(t1, u)
}
```

However, note that binary package uses reflect package, reflect package uses unsafe package.

Comment: The OP is trying to "cast" the entire structure, not just the one field.